# Чем заменить оператор with

Tags: javascript

Чем заменить оператор [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), если всё-таки нужно выполнять код в определённой области видимости (scope)? Специфика задачи позволяет использовать eval, таким образом можно генерировать код ECMAScript:

```
function evalInScope( scope, code ) {
    let keys = scope.keys(),
        values = keys.map(it => scope[it]),
        fn = eval(`new Function( ${ keys.map(key => '"' + key + '"').join(',') }, " return (${ code })") `);

    return fn.apply(context, values);
}
```

Это работает, но кажется неоптимальным решением когда ключей в scope действительно много.

Comment: Если так всё-таки нужно, зачем заменить? Зачем имитировать `with` обходным образом?

Comment: with к сожалению deprecated

Comment: + код будет встраиваться, в тч в strict mode

Comment: @11111000000, `with` не просто так `deprecated`. Это вполне логичное и оправданное решение ;)

Comment: это очевидно, однако бывают специфичные применения, как то - интерпретация кода из строки в определённом контексте, если по условию нельзя использовать this. Альтернативой `with` тут может быть кодогенерация, однако это кажется не слишком естественным для Javascript, несмотря на его отдалённое родство со Scheme. Мне кажется странным что-то убирать из стандарта, не предложив альтернативы, возможно она есть, но мною пока не найдена.

Comment: У вас ни слова нет о том _зачем_ вам это нужно. Формулировка "_Специфика задачи **позволяет** использовать eval_" вовсе не означает, что речь идет о интерпретации кода из строки. Пишете нормальные вопросы -- получите нормальные ответы!

Comment: В вопросе чётко сказано: _если всё-таки нужно выполнять код в определённой области видимости_ , вы же просто попытались сумничать, а теперь обижаетесь как ребёнок непонятно на что. И вопрос минусанули лишь из-за того, что не знаете решения - смешной вы